# How do render data as indented list in html using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

I have json data in my second page. How do i display those data as indented list?

Do I have to use accordion widget from jquery ?

I am newbie in UI development. So please excuse my simple query like this.
Please show me a direction on how to proceed in implementing this. Thanks in advance.

---

```
$.ajax({
                url: "data/widgetData.json",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(jsondata, function(i, item) {
                        $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                            childElements = v['children']
                            $('.header span').text(v.title)
                            $.each(childElements,function(key,value) {
                                // $('#parent1').text(childElements[key].label + '('+childElements[key].deviceName+')')

                                if(childElements[key].children){
                                     for (var i = 0; i < childElements[key].children.length; i++) {

                                     };
                                }
                            });


                        });
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you show us your json structure

Comment: Updated. Please check

Comment: if you have more questions, I will be available in 2-3 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "data/widgetData.json",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
            process(jsondata.widgetData, 0, '#list');
            //it can be process(jsondata, 0, '#list');
            //depends on what console.log(jsonData) returns
        }
    });

function process(items, level, element) {

       $(element).append('<ul></ul>');
       for (var i = 0; i<items.length; i++ ) {

           $(element + '> ul' ).append('<li class="' + level + '-' + i + '"> <img height="10" width="10" style="background:' + items[i].color +'">' + (items[i].label ? items[i].label : items[i].title) + '('+ (items[i].deviceName ? items[i].deviceName : "")  +')' + '<span style="float:right">'+ (items[i].objects ? items[i].objects : "") +'</span></li>');
           if(items[i].children) {
              process(items[i].children, level+1, '.' + level + '-' + i); 
           }
    } 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="list">

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edkvq97f/27/

Modify it as you need. Just put your data instead of `json.widgetData`

Comment: I am reading json data from local file via ajax. `var json;
     $.ajax({
                    url: "data/widgetData.json",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
                        json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    }
                });` I get error **Cannot read property 'widgetData' of undefined**

Comment: It should be datatype: json. And when you do console.log(json) it shouldn't return a bunch text, it should be an object. As soon as you get the object, the code will work

Comment: I have added how I am reading json data using ajax. Need to append those elements inside that function. Can you tell me how to append to container element dynamically?

Comment: check the new link my friend: http://jsfiddle.net/edkvq97f/26/.  This is the best way to render tree like structure. i.e. using recursion.

Comment: @SaidKholov `js` appear to return duplicates items ?

Comment: @guest271314, you mean the js in the fiddle?

Comment: No, it renders what there is in the json file. Some of the items have the same name, maybe that's why it looks the same to you

Comment: @SaidKholov Which `children` `array` within `json` file contains six items ?

Comment: You are welcome:)  Not certain if viewed similar snippet somewhere ? `'<li class="' + level + '-' + i + '"> <img height="10" width="10" style="background:' + items[i].color +'">' + (items[i].label ? items[i].label : items[i].title) + '('+ (items[i].deviceName ? items[i].deviceName : "")  +')' + '<span style="float:right">'+ (items[i].objects ? items[i].objects : "") +'</span></li>')`  ? `'('+ (items[i].deviceName ? items[i].deviceName : "")  +')'` ?

Comment: @SaidKholov _"I wrote it myself:)"_ ? Not appear similar to `js` at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29815367/2801559 ? , in particular, `'('+ (items[i].deviceName ? items[i].deviceName : "")` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean, mate. Do you mean I copied it from you?

Comment: Yes. Nearly identical to updated post at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29815367/2801559 , which was updated before http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29814681/4 ?  _"I wrote it myself:)"_ ? `'('+ (items[i].deviceName ? items[i].deviceName : "")`  was not derived from  `(value.deviceName ? "(" + value.deviceName + ")" : "")` ? Not an issue if that is clearly stated in updated post , or comments . Yet _"I wrote it myself:)"_ ? Really ?

Comment: I didn't copy, I didn't even have a look at it ;).  I don't know any other way of doing it

Comment: Ok . Then must be mistaken, here . Evidently a coincidence; we must have been similarly inspired at similar moment in time ! btw, nice work on the `for` loop ; briefer than own `js` . Cheers:)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    var container = $("#container");
    $.getJSON("data/widgetData.json")
    .then(function(data) {
      $.map(data, function(val, key) {
        container.append("<span class=title>" + val[0].title + "<span>")
        .css("font-size", "16px");
        $.map(val[0].children, function(value, index) {
          var items = function(value, index) {
            var html = "<ul class=item-" + index + " style=list-style:none;>"
                       + "<li><img style=background-color:" + value.color 
                       + ";width:1em;height:1em; /> " + value.label 
                       + (value.deviceName ? "(" + value.deviceName + ")" : "")
                       + "<span style=position:absolute;"
                       + "display:inline-block;left:"
                       + "calc("+(window.innerWidth - 200)+"px) >" 
                       + "☍" + value.objects + "</span></li></ul>";
            return html
          }; 
          container.append(items(container, value, index)); 
          if (!!value.children) {
            var res = $.map(value.children, function(v, k) {
              return items( v, index)
            });
            container.find("[class$="+index+"]").append(res.join(""));
          }
        });
      });
    }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown)
    });
```

```js
var data = {
  "widgetData": [{
    "title": "Example",
    "status": "active",
    "children": [{
      "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
      "deviceName": "device101",
      "color": "red",
      "status": "active",
      "objects": 10,
      "children": [{
        "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
        "color": "red",
        "status": "inactive",
        "objects": 10
      }]
    }, {
      "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
      "deviceName": "device101",
      "color": "green",
      "status": "active",
      "objects": 10,
      "children": [{
        "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
        "color": "green",
        "status": "inactive",
        "objects": 10
      }, {
        "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
        "color": "green",
        "status": "active",
        "objects": 10
      }, {
        "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
        "color": "green",
        "status": "inactive",
        "objects": 10
      }]
    }, {
      "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
      "deviceName": "device101",
      "color": "blue",
      "status": "active",
      "objects": 10,
      "children": [{
        "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
        "color": "blue",
        "status": "inactive",
        "objects": 10
      }, {
        "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
        "color": "blue",
        "status": "inactive",
        "objects": 10
      }, {
        "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
        "color": "blue",
        "status": "active",
        "objects": 10
      }]
    }, {
      "label": "DashboardVirtualSamePool",
      "deviceName": "device101",
      "color": "blue",
      "status": "unknown",
      "objects": 10
    }]
  }]
};

var container = $("#container");

$.map(data, function(val, key) {
  container.append("<span class=title>" + val[0].title + "<span>")
.css("font-size", "16px");
  $.map(val[0].children, function(value, index) {
var items = function(value, index) {
    var html = "<ul class=item-" + index + " style=list-style:none;>"
                 + "<li><img style=background-color:" + value.color 
                 + ";width:1em;height:1em; /> " + value.label 
                 + (value.deviceName ? "(" + value.deviceName + ")" : "")
                 + "<span style=position:absolute;"
                 + "display:inline-block;left:"
                 + "calc("+(window.innerWidth - 200)+"px) >" 
                 + "☍" + value.objects + "</span></li></ul>";
    return html
  }; 
  container.append(items(value, index)); 
     if (!!value.children) {
       var res = $.map(value.children, function(v, k) {
         return items( v, index)
       });
       container.find("[class$="+index+"]").append(res.join(""));
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gmdv4Lf5/4/

Comment: This looks good. Thanks.Please check my updated ajax code. can you show your example with that code?

Comment: i need to display its corresponding children also if its present.

Comment: it is calling `items.call(container, value, index); ` again and adding the extra elements. it should add only one element for first parent and three elements for other two parents as per json data. But for second parents it is adding more than required.How do i fix this?